# Как сделать AutoAiming в радиусе?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Смотрите в чём суть. У меня уже есть рабочий скрипт [image: Вон он]

Он изначально выделяет ВСЕХ юнитов с тегов "Enemy" и переносит их в нужную переменную, но я хочу сделать так что бы они при входе в радиус игрока, переходили в переменную _enemies, а при выходе выходили. Я пытался сделать через OnTrigger, но оно сохраняет только один объект в одиночную переменную GameObject, а при объявлении массива ругается. Как можно решить проблему, пожалуйста подскажите

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AutoAiming : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private GameObject[] _enemies;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject _weapon;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask layerMask;
    private float rotateZ;
    private Vector2 position;
    private GameObject target;


    private void Update()
    {
        position = new Vector2(position.x, position.y);
        _enemies = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy");
        if (_enemies.Length > 0)
        {
            target = _enemies[0];
            for (int i = 0; i < _enemies.Length; i++)
            {
                if (Vector3.Distance(new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y), new Vector2(_enemies[i].transform.position.x, _enemies[i].transform.position.y)) <
                    Vector3.Distance(new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y), new Vector2(target.transform.position.x, target.transform.position.y)))
                    target = _enemies[i];

            }
            Vector3 difference = target.transform.position - transform.position;
            rotateZ = Mathf.Atan2(difference.y, difference.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
            _weapon.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, rotateZ - 90f);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Прикладывай код - кодом, а не картинкой

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не разбираюсь в Unity, поэтому подкорректируйте если где-то не прав, но чисто по логике что-то вроде такого должно быть

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class AutoAiming : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private GameObject[] _closeEnemies;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject _weapon;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask layerMask;
    private float rotateZ;
    private Vector2 position;
    private GameObject target;


    private void Update()
    {
        position = new Vector2(position.x, position.y);
        var allEnemies = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy");
        
        _closeEnemies = allEnemies.Where
            (
                enemy => 
                Vector3.Distance(new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y), new Vector2(enemy.transform.position.x, enemy.transform.position.y))
                < range // whatever is your range
            ).ToArray();
        // do whatever you want with close enemies
    }
}
```

Comment: Я понял твою логику. Я думаю это то что нужно, спасибо большое

Comment: Linq в Update да еще и с материализацией? Тяжеловато по перфу.

Comment: @aepot ну это я фанат linq синтаксиса, если в unity даже такая тривиальщина может заимпактить производительность то можно конечно просто ручками массив перебрать. Может это вообще не нужно пересчитывать каждый фрейм, не знаю)

Comment: @yolosora может, в первую очередь создание массива здесь тяжело. В данном конкретном случае простой перебор через `for` плюс условие решат вопрос точно так же, но скушают 0 лишней памяти и отработают сильно быстрее. Не создавайте лишней работы сборщику мусора. Если бы вы Linq при загрузке данных или при старте скрипта разово использовали, то был бы другой разговор, но не в аптейтах.

Comment: @yolosora представьте что Update при 60 FPS вызывается 60 раз в секунду. А теперь представьте что таких объектов на сцене у вас 1000. Так и получится - создание 60000 массивов в секунду, заимпактит ли это производительность, как считаете?

Comment: @aepot даже не знаю как мне дальше жить с этой информацией, наверное мне сегодня приснится сон с сотнями тысяч массивов атакующих бедных сборщик мусора))